# How to set timestamp on Insert in Model file

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am working with MySQL Workbench for creation of databases and all that jazz.

Now i got a table lets say item:

```
TABLE:   ITEM

COLUMNS: NAME    |   TYPE     |     CREATED_TIMESTAMP
```

Now i created 2 inserts in the model

```
SHOVEL | METAL | <TIMESTAMP>
ROPE   | NYLON | <TIMESTAMP>
```

Question as per above is how to set timestamp for the  marked columns?

Can't figure it out at all, the default CURRENT TIMESTAMP doesn't actually do anything  when i load the model into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

For basic timestamp (date + time) in the relevant column add the below text:

```
\func NOW()
```

Result will be in format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```